# Counting how many times a regex matches in multiple folders

Tags: python, regex

I have recently started using python3 and I'm having some difficulties. Hope someone can help me.
I need a python function that iterates through a lot of files within different subfolders in a bigger folder, to count the total number of occurrences of a given word (even if there's multiple in one line). 
So the result I should get is a number, but the result I actually get is "No results." printed hundreds of times. 
This is the code, can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import so
import re

rootdir = "/path/Desktop/folder"
regex = re.compile(r'\bword\b')
count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if regex.findall(file):
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
        else: 
            print("No results.")
```

Comment: You need to consider that, findall function returns list of items with pattern matched.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 1):

You get `"No results."` over and over again because you print in every loop.

To get the desired result, do this:

```
import os
import re

rootdir = "/path/Desktop/folder"
regex = re.compile(r'\bword\b')
count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if regex.findall(file):
            count = count + 1

if count > 0:
    print(count)
else: 
    print("No results.")
```

Without regex, allowing partial matches:

```
import os

rootdir = "/path/Desktop/folder"
searched_word = "word"
count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if searched_word in file:
            count = count + 1

if count > 0:
    print(count)
else: 
    print("No results.")
```

Comment: You are searching for the word in text file name only with this solution, not searching inside the text file. From what i've understood of OP question, this is not the way to do it

Comment: @reb can you clarify if you need `word` to be in the file name, or the entire path?

Comment: @reb in that case I feel like regex is overkill, and maybe causing the issue. Added a change, that looks for any file containing `"word"`, not requiring to be the start/end.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this regex in order to catch the word if it is internal in other word

```
 \b(\w*word\w*)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the text within the file but actually just looking for the word in the filename. You can do print(file) to see what you are looking into.

```
import os
import re

rootdir = "/path/Desktop/folder"
regex = re.compile(r'\bword\b')
count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:
        with open(f'{path}/{filename}','r'):
            for line in f.readlines():
                if regex.findall(line):
                    count +=1
                    print(count)
```

This might not be the best way to do when working with large files though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring that what you're trying to do is to recursively find any and all text files within a directory structure, open them for reading, count the occurrences of a regex match within each file and tally the total number of occurrences across all files.

In that case, you've neglected to actually open each file as you discover it, and you're not actually counting the occurrences in the file's contents - you're trying to match the regex against the filename. Also, you're currently only incrementing `count` by one if the current filename contains at least one match. It seems to me that you want to increment `count` by however many occurrences were found in the file's contents.

Here's how I might write it. I haven't tested this, but I think it should work:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

pattern = r"\bword\b"

def get_occurrences(path):
    return len(re.findall(pattern, path.read_text()))

total = sum(map(get_occurrences, Path("/path/Desktop/folder").rglob("*.txt")))
if total:
    print(f"Total number of occurrences: {total}"))
else:
    print("No occurrences")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Indeed, you have perfectly understood what I have to do and what I need, thank you again. I tried your script but the function exits without getting any results, neither "No occurences" nor the total number of occurrences, but honestly I can't understand what the problem could be. Also the files to which I have to apply the script are indicated as text/plain and have no extension, so could it be correct to indicate them with .rglob (".")))?

Comment: What utility or software is indicating `text/plain`? To me that suggests a `.txt` extension. If they truly have no extension, you could try changing the glob-pattern to `"*"` to capture all files (any filename, any extension, even missing ones). However, do keep in mind this will also discover any other files that may be located anywhere within your directory structure.

Comment: Also, are there really no errors/exceptions? If there are no errors, the script should output one of the two messages. It's possible that, if you have many files, and each file is very large, that you simply haven't waited long enough for the script to finish.

Comment: 1. I'm on Ubuntu and the file type shown in the info is `plain text document (text/plain)`. The file were automatically generated by a script I could not edit, so I had no choice. But there's nothing else in the directory but these files so I'll definitely go with `"*"`, thank you so much.
2. There are no errors and the script actually ends very early. I'm launching it from the Ubuntu command line and after not even a second it finishes and I can enter a new command, so I think it doesn't even start scrolling through the files.

Comment: Is it possible that the script didn't even run because of the `if __name__ == "__main__"`? I've removed it, try it now.